# How do edge cases work in the Fallen Order restore system (aka getting your XP back when you die)?

Tags: star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

Okay, so after missing the explanation in the tutorial (and not being a Dark Souls player), I finally figured out how the whole, "losing XP when you die and getting it back" (aka the "Restore System") works:

**If an enemy kills you, that enemy glows gold after you re-spawn at your last-used meditation point. If you damage that enemy on your next run, you get your XP back.  Plus your force and health bars are topped off as a bonus.**

But there are still two things I don't get about the system:

1. **What happens if I die from falling off a cliff?** (Or more likely sliding off a cliff because the planet I'm visiting has an improbably roller-coaster like ice slide I have to navigate down?)There's no monster to glow and go after.  Is that XP just lost?
2. **What happens if I'm killed by an enemy, but then get killed by a different enemy after I respawn, but before damaging the first one?** Is the original lost XP gone forever, and I can only recover the *additional* XP earned on the second failed run from the second enemy that killed me? Or are there two glowing enemies, each with the lost XP from the run they ended? Or do they meet up, and conolidate their assets, to take advantage of bulk-pricing in their XP banking services?  Okay, probably not the last one.

One small meta note: I *did* think hard about whether this should be two questions, and am fairly convinced it shouldn't. One page that fully explains the restore system is a lot more useful than 3 that each explain one element of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens if I die from falling off a cliff?

If you die by falling off a cliff, then there will be a gold beam next to the cliff where you fell to your demise. ([Source](https://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/star-wars-jedi-fallen-order-how-to-get-xp-back-after-dying/))

I want to say this is also based on difficulty, but I will need to verify this. During the post game, I bumped the difficult down to story mode to make finding collectibles easier. After many failed attempts to find hard to reach collectibles that can make you fall off a cliff, I never went pasted zero. But again, need to verify

> What happens if I'm killed by an enemy, but then get killed by a different enemy after I respawn, but before damaging the first one?

Based on two sources ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FallenOrder/comments/dwpse0/if_i_die_twice_is_the_xp_gone_forever/f7kr31m/) and [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/240966-star-wars-jedi-fallen-order/78172134)), the death system does seem to work similar to the Dark Souls series. Between the two sources, both indicated that if you die prior to regaining your lost experience, those experience points will be permanently lost.

It was noted on the second source that one guy died twice prior to obtaining his experience, and both enemies had the yellowish glow. Although, whether it was intended behavior or a bug, they were unsure of.

Comment: While the OP doesnt mention this scenario, I had it happen once where I killed a boss but then died somehow after it was dead, but the game still thought I was killing the boss. When it respawned me, the boss did not respawn, but there was a gold beam by the Mantis on the planet where I died.

Comment: The gold beam from dying due to falls still exists on the hardest difficulty level. You'll also get a gold beam if you die to the random bounty hunters who may not be there anymore if you die to them. Also, it should be noted that you only lose experience from the progress you are making towards your next skill point. If you've just gained a skill point and then die, you lose almost zero experience. You cannot lose any amount of experience where you would lose a skill point.